# GQL error reports property is not indexed on dev_appserver?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql, gqlquery

Must be missing something really dumb here. This GQL query:

```
q_count = Questions.gql('WHERE questionnaire = :1 AND deleted = False AND required = True', q).count(1000)
```

generated following error:
`ERROR    2012-12-21 11:19:51,760 _webapp25.py:468] Property 'required' is not indexed`

Even though my index.yaml contains the following entry:

`- kind: Questions
  properties:
  - name: questionnaire
  - name: deleted
  - name: required`

What am I missing!

Comment: if it's a "just uploaded" app it might still be building them perhaps?

Comment: it's on the dev_appserver running locally and the index says it's 'serving'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I feel stupid. Here is the line for 'required' in my `Questions` model:

`required = db.BooleanProperty(default=False, indexed=False)`

doh. The PropertyError which was raised in the log is defined as follows in GAE docs:

`exception PropertyError()
The referenced model property does not exist on the data object.`

Answer (score 0):

For equality-only queries you do [not need to define compound indexes](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes#Index_Configuration).

Comment: seems like this query falls into the following category: `Queries using only ancestor and equality filters` and should therefore have an automatic index (nothing required in index.yaml). So still wondering why I have this error.